# Get Single List Based on Join of Two Sub Lists

Tags: c#, linq, outer-join

I have a list of Items that contain two List sub-properties, I need to get all the (unique) values that are the result of those two sub-properties being joined (but only joined within their parent class). Below is a contrived example:

**Class**

```
public class Calendar
{
    public List<int> Months { get; set; }
    public List<int> Days { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Calendar(int id)
    {
        Months = new List<int>();       
        Days = new List<int>();
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
```

I have a List of Calendar objects, and I need to get a list of the Month/Day combinations from the whole collection. I have managed to do this by joining two SelectMany options together:

```
var years = new List<Calendar>();

var cal2001 = new Calendar(1);  
cal2001.Months = new List<int>() { 1, 2};
cal2001.Days = new List<int>() { 1, 6 };
years.Add(cal2001);

var cal2002 = new Calendar(2);  
cal2002.Months = new List<int>() { 2, 4};
cal2002.Days = new List<int>() { 6, 15 };
years.Add(cal2002);

var items = (from M in years.SelectMany(Y => Y.Months, (Y, result) => new { Month = result, Id = Y.Id })
            join D in years.SelectMany(Y => Y.Days, (Y, result) => new { Day = result, Id = Y.Id }) on M.Id equals D.Id
            select new { Day = D.Day, Month = M.Month }).Distinct();

items.Dump(); //Dump items to output in Linqpad.
```

This gives the desired output of:

```
Day  Month
1    1
6    1
1    2
6    2
15   2
6    4
15   4
```

So this method works, but is there a more efficient manner of performing this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
years.SelectMany(y=> from d in y.Days
                    from m in y.Months
                   select new{d,m})  // cross join
    .Distinct()
    .Dump();
```

This gives the same output.

Moreover, is your request **really** what you want to achieve ? It gives funky results if you have multiple calendars on a same year. For instance, try your request with:

```
var years = new []{
    new Calendar(2001){ Months = { 1 }, Days= { 2 }},
    new Calendar(2001){ Months = { 3 }, Days= { 4 }},
};
```

=> this gives (2,1), (4,1), (2,3), (4,3) ... is this the intended result ? (if yes, my request doesnt work)

Comment: I *knew* it had to be easier than I'd thought. This appears to work a treat!

In reality, the "year" is actually an ID, so it's fine, I'll update the example code to make it clearer, but your solution works just fine for my requirement.

Comment: @Olivier: Why do you say that last example would give four elements. I tried it and it gave exactly what it expected. `SelectMany` will operate independently on each element of the years array and won't care if two or more elements have the same year. And yes, I actually ran it to confirm and I get two results out in my enumerable. Not that it seems to be relevant to the OP but it'd be nice to update the answer to be more correct in this case. :)

Comment: @Chris yep, it gives only 2 results with my request (that's what I would expect), but the original request (which Obsidian Phoenix gave in his question) yields 4 results !

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, poor reading on my part. So you were highlighting basically that yours was correcting what you perceived as probably problems. You've got my +1 now! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `IEqualityComparer` you can use `Distinct` to weed out the duplicates. I've introduced a name class `DateEntry` which corresponds to the anonymous type you had. I also implemented `IComparable` in order to be able to sort the results.

```
public class DateEntryComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateEntry>
{   
    public bool Equals(DateEntry lhs, DateEntry rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Day == rhs.Day && lhs.Month == rhs.Month;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateEntry entry)
    {
        return entry.Day.GetHashCode() ^ entry.Month.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class DateEntry : IComparable<DateEntry>
{
    public int Day {get;set;}
    public int Month {get;set;} 

    public int CompareTo(DateEntry entry)
    {
        var result = Month.CompareTo(entry.Month);

        if(result == 0)
        {
            result = Day.CompareTo(entry.Day);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Calendar
{
    public List<int> Months { get; set; }
    public List<int> Days { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public Calendar(int year)
    {
        Months = new List<int>();       
        Days = new List<int>();
        Year = year;
    } 

    public IEnumerable<DateEntry> GetDateEntries()
    {
        return from d in Days 
               from m in Months
               select new DateEntry { Day = d, Month = m };
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var items = years.SelectMany(y => y.GetDateEntries()).Distinct(new DateEntryComparer()).OrderBy(x => x);
    items.Dump(); //Dump items to output in Linqpad.
```

Output:

```
1 1 
6 1 
1 2 
6 2 
15 2 
6 4 
15 4
```